click a drop-down button without making its status tip disappear
A dialog has several widgets including a qpushbutton with a dropdown menu. A statustip appears when you hover over the button (I use an enterEvent() because the button is enabled only under certain conditions but I would like the tips even when the button is disabled).
Also, when the button has focus the statustip is shown even if the mouse cursor is not over the button.
Problem:
The statustip disappears when you click the button once to open the dropdown menu (which opens regularly on the first click).
below is an MRE
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog, QLineEdit, QMenu,
                             QPushButton, QStatusBar, QVBoxLayout,
                            )
from PyQt5 import QtGui

class myDialog(object):

    def setup(self, Dialog):

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit = MyLineEdit()
        self.button = myButton()
        svg = "/path/to/local/icon.svg"  #  <<<<< to customize
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(svg))
        Dialog.setWindowIcon(icon)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)


class myButton(QPushButton):

    def __init__(self):
        super(myButton, self).__init__()
        menu = QMenu()
        self.act_1 = menu.addAction('Action 1', self._1)
        self.act_11 = menu.addAction('Action 11', self._11)
        self.setMenu(menu)
        self.tip = "Button tip"

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        super(myButton, self).enterEvent(event)
        self.prev_message = bar.currentMessage()
        bar.showMessage(self.tip)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        super(myButton, self).leaveEvent(event)
        bar.showMessage("no longer button tip")

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        super(myButton, self).focusInEvent(event)
        bar.showMessage(self.tip)

    def _1(self):
        pass

    def _11(self):
        pass

class MyLineEdit(QLineEdit):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyLineEdit, self).__init__()
        self.tip = "Line edit tip"

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        super(MyLineEdit, self).enterEvent(event)
        self.prev_message = bar.currentMessage()
        bar.showMessage(self.tip)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        super(MyLineEdit, self).leaveEvent(event)
        bar.showMessage("")

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        super(MyLineEdit, self).focusOutEvent(event)
        bar.showMessage(self.prev_message)

    def focusInEvent(self, event):
        self.prev_message = bar.currentMessage()
        bar.showMessage(self.tip)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QDialog()
    ui = myDialog()
    ui.setup(Dialog)
    bar = QStatusBar(Dialog)
    ui.layout.addWidget(bar)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


desired behavior:
When clicking the button, the dropdown menu appears while the correct statustip remains visible.
actual behavior:
The first time, when clicking the button, the dropdown menu opens and the correct statustip remains  displayed. Starting from the second time the same procedure is repeated, the statustip disappears when clicking the button and does not return unless the focus is first moved to another widget.
Even worse if I set QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb (0) before running the script: from the first time, when clicking the button, the dropdown opens but the correct statustip disappears.
My attempts:
if I  only manage focusInEvent and leave out enterEvent and leaveEvent the button never loses its statustip when the dropdown opens (and this happens even if before running the script I set QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb): however in this way I only have the tips when the button has the focus, therefore only if the button is enabled.
(0) Reasons for setting QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb:

dialog centered on the screen instead of open in the first free space at the top left.
window icon and icon on the taskbar are correct, otherwise only the generic Wailand icon appears.
occasionally instead of the dropdown menu a small window containing the menu opens on the screen next to the dialog; and in these cases the terminal displays:
qt.qpa.wayland: Wayland does not support QWindow::requestActivate()


Hover and Enter/Leave events are related, but not always coinciding. This may be an issue for complex cases that relate to Popup widgets (such as QMenu) and especially considering the often inconsistent scenario of window/focus management on Linux; Wayland adds further complications to that. Unfortunately, since QMenu is a Popup window, it prevents proper event propagation until closed. A possible work around could be to enforce the status tip upon menu displaying, using a QMenu subclass and overriding its showEvent(), calling the related function with a singleShot QTimer.

Thanks for the input. If you would like to elaborate the workaround you propose in the form of an answer I would be happy to accept it as a solution.

I've done some simple tests and even in an older and "non-standard" X11 environment I've noticed some unexpected behavior. I will consider taking time to check it out and eventually provide an answer, but I'm not making any promise. As said, your case is a bit peculiar, and may depend on very specific X/Wayland combinations that cannot be considered as "standard" even by large. In the meantime, I'd suggest you to take your time and study the official C++ sources, and also consider using "common" QStatusTipEvent, which may be more effective in more abstract environments.
